# How to display selected attributes for selected levels in DOORS using DXL?

Tags: ibm-doors, ibm-rational

I'm looking for some DXL/DOORS help...

I have 3 modules: A, B, and C.  B is linked in to A, and C is linked in to B. So B is depth 1 and C is depth 2. I am trying to create a column in A that displays the object text, module name, and object number of the inlinked objects from B and C.  However, I do not want to display all 3 of these (text, name, number) for both B and C--instead I'd like to only display the object text from B and the module name and object number from C. Ideally I want the info from C to be in square brackets immediately following the info from B. I would like it to look like this:

Within a column in A:
"object text from B" ["module name of C" "object number of C"]

I have used the wizard to create the below layout DXL script, but currently it shows all 3 pieces of information for both B and C. Does anyone have any suggestions on how to print out only object text from B (depth 1), followed by module name and object number from C (depth 2)?

Note: In the below script, I tweaked the end to display s, p, and t in the order I would like them.

```
// DXL generated by DOORS traceability wizard on 27 October 2014.
// Wizard version 2.0, DOORS version 9.5.2.1
pragma runLim, 0
const int indentStep = 360
Buffer indentBuff = create
Buffer lineBuff = create
lineBuff = "______________________"
string indentAllParagraphs(string s, bool addBullets, int addedIndent)
{
    int numParas = 0
    RichTextParagraph rtp
    indentBuff = s
    for rtp in s do
    {
        numParas++
        Buffer t = create()
        t += rtp.text
        if (length(t) > 0 )
        {
            bool hasBullet = rtp.isBullet
            int  indentLev = rtp.indentLevel
            indentBuff = applyTextFormattingToParagraph(indentBuff, hasBullet, indentLev+addedIndent, numParas)
        }
        delete(t)
    }
    return (numParas == 0 ? "" : tempStringOf(indentBuff))
}
int lines[2] = {0, 0}
void adjustLines(int depth, showAtDepth) {
    int count
    for (count = 0; count < 2; count++) {
        while (lines[depth-1] < lines[count]) {
            if (depth == showAtDepth) displayRich("\\pard " " ")
            lines[depth-1]++
        }
    }
}
void showIn(Object o, int depth) {
    Link l
    LinkRef lr
    ModName_ otherMod = null
    Module linkMod = null
    ModuleVersion otherVersion = null
    Object othero
    string disp = null
    string s = null
    string plain, plainDisp
    int plainTextLen
    int count
    bool doneOne = false
    string linkModName = "*"
    for lr in all(o<-linkModName) do {
        otherMod = module (sourceVersion lr)
        if (!null otherMod) {
            if ((!isDeleted otherMod) && (null data(sourceVersion lr))) {
                load((sourceVersion lr),false)
            }
        }
    }
    for l in all(o<-linkModName) do {
        otherVersion = sourceVersion l
        otherMod = module(otherVersion)
        if (null otherMod || isDeleted otherMod) continue
        othero = source l
        if (null othero) {
            load(otherVersion,false)
        }
        othero = source l
        if (null othero) continue
        if (isDeleted othero) continue
        int oldLines = lines[depth-1]
        doneOne = true
        {
            s = name(otherMod)
            p = probeRichAttr_(othero,"Object Number", false)
            t = probeRichAttr_(othero,"Object Text", false)
            displayRich(t" ""["s" "p"]")
        }
        lines[depth-1] += 3
        if ( depth < 2 ) {
            showIn(othero, depth+1)
        }
    }
}
showIn(obj,1)
delete indentBuff
delete lineBuff
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I'd approach it:

**In Module B:**
Create a DXL attribute that pulls in the info you want from Module C, *e.g.*, an attribute called "C Object Info" that collects Module Name and Object Number. (I usually do this via Analysis > Wizard,  then use Tools > Support Tools > Convert Layout DXL to Attribute DXL, then tweak the DXL). So each object in Module B that has an in-link from Module C will have this attribute "C Object Info" that can be accessed in Module A.

**In Module A:**
Create a DXL layout (via Analysis > Wizard) that pulls in and formats the info you want from Module B: "Object Text [C Object Info]"

[I don't know if it's Good DOORS Practice to do it like this, but it makes the scripting a little easier. When I know I'm going to be taking chunks of info like "[Object ID] Object Text" across multiple levels of linking hierarchy (*e.g.*, going from Module A customerRequirement to Module B systemRequirement to Module C subsystemRequirement, I'll have a DXL attribute for customerRequirement and subsystemRequirement in my systemRequirement module so I can access/display/manipulate the data from more than one link level away. It comes in handy for traceability reports, developing verification/validation procedures, etc.]